# Hello, I am a pretty big number. Add a line to make me many things

Tags: lateral-thinking, formation-of-numbers

I am a pretty big number:

[image]

Here are a few challenges for you:

1. Add a line to make me a millennium.
2. Add a line to make me a millennium and ten.
3. Add a line to make me a century and one.
4. Add a line to make me a time.
5. Add a line to make me lunch.
6. Add a squiggle to make me the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.

> Note that a straight line is meant by “line”, and also, none of these parts are related to each other (ie. always add the line/squiggle to the original image).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Add a line to make me a millennium.

   > Add a horizontal line before the third 1. 1010 - 10 = 1000
2. Add a line to make me a millennium and ten.

   > Cross the third 1. 1010 + 0 = 1010
3. Add a line to make me a century and one.

   > Add a slash before the third 1. 1010/10 = 101
4. Add a line to make me a time.

   > **Incorrect Guess :(** <strike>Either a slash, or a dash depending on how you prefer dates. 10/1010 or 1010-10 (October 1010)</strike>
   > From @Deusovi: Add a line above the second 1 to make it a T. 10TO10 (10 minutes to 10)
5. Add a line to make me lunch.

   > Strikethrough the entire line to make a kebob. <strike>. 101010 .</strike>
6. Add a squiggle to make me the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.

   > Add the subscript 2 to make it binary. $101010_2$

Comment: Wow!!! Almost all of them. Just not the one I was thinking about for number 4 :)

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of a time as in 12pm, etc.

Comment: Add a line to the top for #4: "10TO10".

Comment: Correct. Nicely done - I was surprised anyone would get the kebab one so quickly.

Comment: @QuestionAsker The kebab one was the only one i got, reading this question.

Comment: My first thought was binary, and I didn't even think about subscript.